# Add HTML to popover title in ngx-bootstrap

Tags: angular, popover, ngx-bootstrap

I'm trying to add a line break to a popover title in `ngx-bootstrap`.

Is that possible?

The line break tag below comes out as text, and for some reason `ng-template` seems to be within the popover body (not clear how to add title).

```
<ng-template #popTemplate>Just another: {{content}}</ng-template>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"
        [popover]="popTemplate" popoverTitle="Template ref <BR> content inside">
  TemplateRef binding
</button>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ohncpd

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you cannot add HTML in the title.

But that doesn't mean we can't improvise

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ohncpd-lbhdgg?file=app/custom-content.html

```
  <h3 class="popover-title popover-header" style="margin: -.5rem -.75rem 0 -.75rem;">Template ref <BR> content inside</h3>
  Just another: {{content}}

  </ng-template>



<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning"
        [popover]="popTemplate" >
  TemplateRef binding
</button>
```